# how do i find a hash for a chunk of file without having to save the chunk in a separate file?

Tags: hash, vbscript, md5, adodb, extract

I want to find a hash for a chunk of file and save that hash in another file. I want to do it directly without having to save the chunk in a separate file.. here is my program.

```
 Const chunksize = 1024000000
 dim istream,ostream
  Sub WriteChunk(data)
   Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
   oStream.Open
   oStream.Type = 1 
   oStream.Write data

   Dim WshShell, oExec, input,objfile2,str1
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Set oExec    = WshShell.exec("C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\experimenting\md5.exe_
                             -odup5.txt """ & ostream.write & """")

   input = ""
      Do While oexec.status=0
     WScript.Sleep 50
     Loop
     oStream.Close
   End Sub

    Set iStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     iStream.Open
   iStream.Type = 1  'binary
    Const FOR_READING = 1

     strFolder = "C:\test" 

     Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

     Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

     For Each objFile In colFiles
      iStream.LoadFromFile objfile.path
        Do Until istream.EOS
      WriteChunk iStream.Read(chunksize)


      loop 


     Next

     ShowSubFolders(objFolder)


   Sub ShowSubFolders(objFolder)

   Set colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders

       For Each objSubFolder In colFolders

      set colFiles = objSubFolder.Files

      For Each objFile2 In colFiles


      iStream.LoadFromFile objfile2.path
      Do Until istream.EOS
      WriteChunk iStream.Read(chunksize)



        loop 
        Next

        ShowSubFolders(objSubFolder)

       Next

     End Sub


       iStream.Close
```

ostream.write cannot be used as an argument. But i am not understanding as to what can be used instead of that..please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set oExec = WshShell.exec("C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\experimenting\md5.exe_
                     -odup5.txt """ & ostream.write & """")
```

The above will fail, because you can't use line-wrapping inside strings. Also, `ostream.write` means you're trying to write something *to* an ADODB Stream object. What you actually want to do (assuming I understood your question correctly and you're using [this](http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/) `md5.exe`) is something like this:

```
WshShell.Run "C:\...\md5.exe -ochunk_md5.txt -d""" & data & """"
```

To write the results of all chunks of data to the same file, do something like this:

```
WshShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c md5.exe -o- -d""" & data & """>chunk_md5.txt", 1, True
```

or like this:

```
Set md5 = WshShell.Exec("md5.exe -o- -d""" & data & """")
Do While md5.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
objFSO.OpenTextFile("chunk_md5.txt", 8, True).Write md5.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Or you could use [this VBScript](https://github.com/Wikinaut/md5.vbs/blob/master/md5.vbs) for calculating the hash and write the result to a file.

Comment: WshShell.Run "C:\...\md5.exe -ochunk_md5.txt -d""" & data & """"  is not working.. it says type mismatch

Comment: I am trying to write the hash of all the chunks to a file. what i dont want is the chunk to be separately saved in a file.